# How can I make an observable emit only latest value and not past values

Tags: rxjs, angular6, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

I have a `ConnectableObservable` which is part of a `BehaviourSubject`.

```
question$: ConnectableObservable<Result>;
private questionSubject: BehaviorSubject<Result>; 

this.questionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Result>(new Result('initial',{}));
this.question$ = (this.questionSubject.asObservable()).pipe(publish()) as ConnectableObservable<Result>;
```

I use `next` method to `emit` values when response from the server is received.

```
this.questionSubject.next(new Result(response.result,getQuestionResponse));
```

It seems that the `Subject` is emitting past values as well.

```
    jsonQuestion response:  {"question-id":"78830909-b23e-4345-bc69-63f3ce039b20",...} //SUBJECT SENDS THIS
question-details.component.ts:369 got stream value  Result {result: "success", additionalInfo: "{"question-id":"78830909-b23e-4345-bc69-63f3ce039b…2-ae23-f284213ff80a"},"is-question-creator":true}"}// OBSERVABLE RECEIVED THIS
... AND THE SAME TRACE COMES AGAIN!!
question-details.component.ts:369 got stream value  Result {result: "success", additionalInfo: "{"question-id":"78830909-b23e-4345-bc69-63f3ce039b…2-ae23-f284213ff80a"},"is-question-creator":true}"}
```

Why is the Observable sending multiple values. How can i make it send only the latest value?

Comment: That's what `BehaviorSubject` does. It always emits the buffered value first.

Comment: maybe you need to use Subject instead?

Comment: Do you have multiple subscriptions to this.question$? What does your detail code look like that is generating these messages?

Comment: DeborahK - you genius! The problem was indeed multiple subscriptions. My component will subscribe but I wasn't unsubscribing on `onDestroy`. For the benefit of everyone, could you please submit an answer with explanation why multiple subscriptions were the issue?

Comment: Done ................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see multiple identical messages emitted from Subject or BehaviorSubject, the problem may be that you have multiple subscriptions.

You can have multiple subscriptions by literally subscribing multiple times, or by not appropriately disposing of subscriptions.

I'd have to see your subscriptions to be more specific. :-)